# How SharePoint traffic is working (SP 2013 on-premise) in multi-tier farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, network

I'm asking myself how communication in a multi-tier SharePoint 2013 farm actually works if I should put it in a simple network schema. The farm has 1 front-end server, 1 database server, 1 search server, 1 application server and 1 Office Web Apps server

For example which servers are used when:

- A user logs in into the SharePoint intranet: I assume this will have traffic between the front-end server and the database server, right?
- A user performs a search query in SharePoint: (the query processing part is on the front-end server, the rest is on the search server). The call goes from the front-end to the database and the search server, right? Or are the results already in the database server?
- A user opens a file in Office Web Apps:  Does the SharePoint goes from the front-end directly to the web apps server with use of the database server?

These are just a few examples. Are these right and is there any documentation about this? I can't find a lot on the internet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A user requests a web page by typing the web address in a browser. Out of two type of request GET request(Put request is used in entering request on server i.e. filling forms) makes a connection with web server, webserver send the requested page to the client in html format. SharePoint get it from Cache or from the Database server.
2. When user type a query, web services on WFe get this request and WFE foward it to search server and search server/service check index and return the results. [check this]
3. I think OWA is same from WFE it ask OWA for view. check this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219435(v=office.15).aspx they have some diagram in this which explain you more.

[1](https://ashishbanga.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/how-search-works-in-sharepoint-basic-concept/)